# Sidekiq Worker vs Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

What is the difference between a worker and a job in the sidekiq context? I was looking and I didn't really find a clear answer. Are they just the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Worker` is the old term, `Job` is the modern term. They are the same thing, Sidekiq made the change to adopt industry standard terminology.